# sudo -u user bash works but $HOME is not changing accordingly

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, home, programming

I'm writing a script to setup new debian install's.
The problem is in this code:

```
if [ ! -z "$USER1" ]
then
    sudo -u "$USER1" bash <<-EOF
    cp "$BASHRC $HOME"/.bashrc
    wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
    echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
    . "$HOME"/.bashrc
    echo "Here is LS_COLORS in action: "
    ls -l "$HOME"/ 
EOF
```

**PROBLEM:**

When I sudo to another user the $HOME variable is not showing/changing this new users home directory.

**QUESTIONS**:

Can you explain to me the problem?

How would I do this in the best and efficient way?

Edit:

Why do I keep getting "`cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory`" or "`cp: missing opereand`" in my cp command? I think it has something to do with $HOME again..........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The here-doc content is evaluated BEFORE the `sudo` is called. This means that every instance of `$HOME` is in the context of the caller, not the `sudo`. You can see this in action here:

```
A=apple
bash <<-EOF
A=banana
echo "$A"
EOF
```

The output is

```
apple
```

If you quote your `EOF` marker its contents will be quoted correspondingly:

```
A=apple
bash <<-'EOF'
A=banana
echo "$A"
EOF
```

Output

```
banana
```

Comment: wow that's great it runs correctly now