# How to have access to script variables and environmental variables inside a sudo/EOF clause in a script......BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, programming, access-control

**PROBLEM:**

I am struggling with this `cp` always giving errors because the variables not there...

Here is my code:

```
if [ ! -z "$USER1" ]
then
     sudo -u "$USER1" bash <<'EOF'
     sleep 5
     BASHRC=.bashrc
     cp "$BASHRC" "$HOME"/.bashrc
     sleep 5
     wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
     sleep 5
     echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
     . "$HOME"/.bashrc
     sleep 5
     echo "Here is LS_COLORS in action: "
     ls -l "$HOME"
EOF
fi
```

**QUESTIONS:**

How to make my script-varibles and environmental variables accessable inside the sudo clauses(there are many)?

Is it sudo or is it here-document that has a problem with this?

EDIT:

Removing the quotes on EOF gives me a previous problem:

```
./testing3892739.sh billy
cp: failed to access '/root/.bashrc': Permission denied
```

EDIT2:

Now the script looks like this.....

```
    if [ ! -z "$USER1" ]
108 then
109     sudo -i -u "$USER1" bash <<'EOF'
110     sleep 5
111     cp -f .bashrc "$HOME"/.bashrc
112     sleep 5
113     wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
114     sleep 5
115     echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
116     . "$HOME"/.bashrc
117     sleep 5
118     echo "Here is LS_COLORS in action: "
119     ls -l "$HOME"
120 EOF
121 fi
```

the `-i` switch to `sudo` made the difference on the last problem....
but as usual and for some time now and many different errors, `cp` gives an **error** and now it is

```
cp: '.bashrc' and '/home/billy/.bashrc' are the same file
```

The file exist's but I need it to be overwritten.

I simply want my script to `cp` the hidden file `.bashrc` from current `dir` which can be anywhere because this is the dir the script resides and files needed for the update of the server, into `$HOME` and overwrite if it's existing.

Comment: Bearing in mind your previous question [sudo -u user bash works but $HOME is not changing accordingly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463282/sudo-u-user-bash-works-but-home-is-not-changing-accordingly) I assume you want `$HOME` to expand to `$USER1`'s home directory - to achieve that, you probably need to invoke a *login shell* by adding `-i` or `--login` to your `sudo` invocation.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks man.......great resource for assitstance this site I just love this place

Comment: @steeldriver then I get this error `cp: '.bashrc' and '/home/billy/.bashrc' are the same file` no problem when I do this for root

Comment: Maybe take a step back and explain what you want your code to do?

Comment: @steeldriver Ok I will take some breathers and a coffee and write a edit what's going on with the script, your input solved the former problem but I'm still not over the hill where the grass is greener

Comment: @steeldriver see my updated edit2........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So (based on comments) you want `.bashrc` to refer to a file in the directory from which `sudo` is invoked; but `$HOME` to expand to the home directory of the target user. I *think* the way to do that is to use `-H`:

> ```
>  -H, --set-home
>              Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
>              variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
>              password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
>              be the default behavior.
> ```

To illustrate:

```
$ sudo -Hu testuser bash -c 'echo \$PWD = $PWD; echo \$HOME = $HOME' 
$PWD = /home/steeldriver/forums/tests
$HOME = /home/testuser
```

whereas with "regular" `sudo` `$HOME` resolves to that of the invoking user

```
$ sudo -u testuser bash -c 'echo \$PWD = $PWD; echo \$HOME = $HOME'
$PWD = /home/steeldriver/forums/tests
$HOME = /home/steeldriver
```

while with a login shell `$HOME` resolves to that of the target user - but the working directory changes there as well:

```
$ sudo -iu testuser bash -c 'echo \$PWD = $PWD; echo \$HOME = $HOME'
/home/testuser = /home/testuser
/home/testuser = /home/testuser
```

neither of which are very useful in your application.

Bear in mind that `sudo` is quite configurable and the default behavior may be different depending on your precise flavor and distribution of Unix/Linux.

Comment: A little misunderstanding is that the `.` is for hidden file in the current dir

Comment: @somethingSomething doh - yes of course, been a long day ;)

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough....... please

Comment: Wow I just understood the logic, hahaha your the best thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<<'EOF'`. If you use `<<EOF` without the quotes, your shell will expand the variables. If there are variables you don't want expanded by your shell, quote them with `\$`.